# Why were my terminations showing open on the same pair but all the cables work?

Tags: cabling

I will start by saying I do not understand the theory behind any of this. I only know how to terminate and run wire. My friend ran ethernet cables through his house (extremely poorly with tons of severe kinks) and he called me to terminate them with RJ45 plugs.

When I tested them, almost every single one showed the white orange/orange pair as open. My eyes are good enough that I can see each individual conductor inside the plug without issue and both ends of every wire looked correct, correct order and evenly crimped. There were about 30 wires and about 25 failed in this exact same way. If they all failed differently I would've thought it was the wire and reran them properly but the fact it was the same failure every time made me think it was my crimper maybe not crimping that pair down all the way.

So I bought a brand new crimper and recrimped a few and had the same issue. So then I tried a different tester. Same issue. The plugs were also rated for that exact cable so that can't be it either unless it was a defective batch. But the weird thing is I got so frustrated with it I plugged one in and it worked so I plugged the rest in and they all worked. My only guess is the poor condition the wire was in was making it fail on the testers I used but they still work to some extent.

I have had this happen a few other times as well where a cable's plugs will look fine but a pair or pairs shows as open. Often terminating again fixes it despite the order inside the plugs being correct and the conductors visibly crimped down the same both times but I never really thought anything of it since it'd only be 1 cable that did that.

I just don't understand why it was the same pair on every wire showing as open. Made me think my crimper wasn't crimping properly or something was up with my tester but a completely different crimper and tester produced the same results. I also questioned my sanity and successfully crimped 20 cables in a row that I'll use as patch cables with my crimper and tester and the same box of plugs at home so that wasn't the issue either.

Comment: Which wiring standard did you use? Also did you speed test the cables?

Comment: https://www.cablinginstall.com/design-install/article/16466578/practical-impacts-of-bend-radius-on-twistedpair-cable-installation ?

Comment: Was it negotiating gigabit connecrions? You can connect at 100 megabits with only 2 pairs - so it may be working without the orange pair.

Comment: What kind of tester did you use? Have you tested *the tester* on a known good cable (pre-made patch cord from store)?